# React app showing blank page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, reactjs

So Im creating a webpage using react,but when I click on index.html it doesnt show anything. Anyone got any ideas about what it may be? Im pretty noob so it should be something very simple. It doesnt show any erros or anything,just the title and the page is all blank. The page is supposed to be very simple and based on one I saw on the web,but it`s not working. Any help will be greatly apreciated.

I`m using ubuntu by the way,not sure if it will be useful.

```
index.html:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>React Bruce</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
      </body>
    </html>

...............................
index.css

    body {
      background-color: #FFCC00;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 0;
    }
    h1, h2, p, ul, li {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    ul.header li {
      display: inline;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
    }
    ul.header {
      background-color: #111;
      padding: 0;
    }
    ul.header li a {
      color: #FFF;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .content {
      background-color: #FFF;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    .content h2 {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .content li {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

.........................
index.js

    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import Main from "./Main";
    import "./index.css";

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Main/>, 
      document.getElementById("root")
    );

    .active {
      background-color: #0099FF;
    }

..................................
Main.js

    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import {
      Route,
      NavLink,
      HashRouter
    } from "react-router-dom";
    import Home from "./Home";
    import Stuff from "./Stuff";
    import Contact from "./Contact";

    class Main extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
             <HashRouter>
            <div>
              <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
              <ul className="header">
               <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/stuff">Stuff</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
              </ul>
              <div className="content">
              <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/stuff" component={Stuff}/>
                <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>

              </div>
            </div>
               <HashRouter>
        );
      }
    }


    export default Main;

...............................
Home.js

import React, { Component } from "react";

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>HELLO</h2>
        <p>Cras facilisis urna ornare ex volutpat, et
        convallis erat elementum. Ut aliquam, ipsum vitae
        gravida suscipit, metus dui bibendum est, eget rhoncus nibh
        metus nec massa. Maecenas hendrerit laoreet augue
        nec molestie. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
        dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

        <p>Duis a turpis sed lacus dapibus elementum sed eu lectus.</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
........................
Stuff.js

import React, { Component } from "react";

class Stuff extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>STUFF</h2>
        <p>Mauris sem velit, vehicula eget sodales vitae,
        rhoncus eget sapien:</p>
        <ol>
          <li>Nulla pulvinar diam</li>
          <li>Facilisis bibendum</li>
          <li>Vestibulum vulputate</li>
          <li>Eget erat</li>
          <li>Id porttitor</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Stuff;
.....................
Contact.js

import React, { Component } from "react";

class Contact extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>GOT QUESTIONS?</h2>
        <p>The easiest thing to do is post on
        our <a href="http://forum.kirupa.com">forums</a>.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Contact;
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to load the site using a local server to render the js on the index.html file.

Comment: You need to install node on your system, then npm, then other dependencies via npm for your react application which includes for example, babel for es6 conversion.

Comment: Here you go: https://codeburst.io/installing-reactjs-and-creating-your-first-application-d437706498ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly write react code into your javascript files.
You need to import the CDN links, in case you are not using any of the building libraries like `webpack`. For reference, you can check out [here.](https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-react-jsx/)

In case you need to start using React with `webpack`, you can install [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) into your machine and set up a basic `react` project with [CRA.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app)

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to include your `js` (and `css` too) in your `html`. Also, the `js` you've provided seems to be written in es6 with imports. It will not run directly in browser.

I suggest you to use a tool like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) to compile your entire js and css with dependencies into a single bundle (a javascript file which includes all your imports) and then include the bundle into your html with `<script></script>`